# VSCode: running the exact same terminal command produces different results depending on if it was run by clicking a UI button

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

## problem

Consider the following terminal command:

`PS C:\dev>  c:; cd 'c:\dev'; & C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe' 'c:\Users\{user}\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python 2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '60106' '--' 'c:\dev\open.py'`

This line is generated and run when I click the "Debug Python File" button in the VSCode UI (top-right). Through this method, the debugger runs the file just fine. If I instead manually run the exact same line in the terminal, I get the following error:

`ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`
*There are more details, can include if necessary*

## question

What do I not understand that's tripping this up? VSCode must be doing something in addition to running this command line, what is it? I'm struggling to come up with the correct search query to find what I need to understand here.

## environment

I'm using VSCode with the Python extensions package installed. As standard an environment as I could get.

## purpose

I'm trying to figure out the quickest/easiest way to run my script, from VSCode, with the debugger, with command line arguments, rather than specifying args in the launch config.

Comment: what if you take out the `'c:\Users\{user}\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python 2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '60106'` part? Do you need that part when you run in your own terminal?

Comment: That worked to run the script! Unfortunately without the debugger... I'm now guessing that part of the VSCode Python debug file command is to launch a debug service listening to a port, *then* run the command from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, the debugging using the UI button will load the configuration in launch.json, and its commands are generated by the extension, there is complexity, so direct and simple copying cannot be used. You can observe that the port changes in every command that uses the UI button to debug.

##### If you want to use the [command line for debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_command-line-debugging), follow the syntax:

```
python -m debugpy
    --listen | --connect
    [<host>:]<port>
    [--wait-for-client]
    [--configure-<name> <value>]...
    [--log-to <path>] [--log-to-stderr]
    <filename> | -m <module> | -c <code> | --pid <pid>
    [<arg>]...
```

***Simple example:***

[image]

##### More information about vscode debugging:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger